# Is it ok to create a wrapper for constructors?

Tags: php, architecture, constructor

We in our Company are discussing is it better to build an Wrapper around an Constructor or to use directly the Constructor. 
So is the use of this ok?

```
public function createUser($number, $firstname, $lastname) {
        return new User($number, $firstname, $lastname);
    }
```

Example:

```
$user = $this->createUser($number, $resultList->firstname, $resultList->lastname);
```

or

```
$user = new User($number, $firstname, $lastname);
```

Comment: Yes, there are actually multiple design patterns that rely on this technique.

Comment: `factory pattern`? you are discussing design pattens yeah

Comment: Zend Framework 2 is using this :-) They have implemented the IoC in a way I almost like it - using constructor dependency injection that is satisfied by service locator for which You may write a factory classes that are Your *constructor wrappers* (or just use closures for the same purpose). So, **Yes, it is OK** until You are misusing or overusing it for something else...

Comment: In practice (coupling, testability etc) there's no difference between an internal factory method and using the `new` operator - really you're just deferring it. That's not to say they aren't useful - I often use them for injecting common components into the created objects, so I can keep the arg list clean for "real" arguments (e.g. http://3v4l.org/k7P68). However this is mostly just DRY and readability. But there is a big difference between internal factory methods (http://3v4l.org/KReul - what you seem to show above) and external factory objects (http://3v4l.org/RMpHZ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm not sure your example is probably ideal, you can absolutely wrap constructors in different functions.

[This is a great read](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) which do use wrappers to create really useful design patterns.

Note the [factory](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#factory) pattern and the [singleton](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#singleton) both use this technique.